# How to group by and create a calculated field in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dataset where 2 flights have the same origin and have the same destination for one date. I want to create a calculated field that divides a 4th column value by the number of flights having same origin,destination and date.[For example in the image attached as there are 2 flights from Boston to  Atlanta on the same day, Flt cube column will be Cap Value/number of flights]. How do I do that in the formula for calculated field.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g15Il.png)

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a calculated field that concatenates the orgin and destination, so that the value is BostonAtlanta and that is a countable value. Lets call this DA_Dimension1.

```
[origin]+[destination]
```

2) Then create a count of the concatenated column, as calculation1:

```
COUNT(DA_Dimension1)
```

3) Create your FLT Cube column:

```
[Calculation1]/ATTR([Capvalue])
```

[Example excel file using your data](https://jmp.sh/fu64UwW) to feed [Example tableau document with the example fields](https://jmp.sh/2f0yZ7g)